# Speed Control using MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android, media-player

I want to control the playback speed using MediaPlayer(not SoundPool).
In here, I read that the MediaPlayer doesn't support speed contorl. So I'll edit the Android Source.
But I don't know where to start. Where should I edit? what's the file that related to the speed control?

If anyone know about this, please give me some advices.